# Windows application error - Windows Universal runtime version

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I'm trying to build a windows application. But I'm running to the below error. I tried to download the version 10.0.18362.0 and rebuild the solution, but still runs into the same error.

"DEP3321: To deploy this application, your deployment target should be running Windows Universal Runtime version 10.0.18362.0 or higher. You currently are running version 10.0.17763.1397. Please update your OS, or change your deployment target to a device with the appropriate version."

Appreciate any suggestions on how to proceed.

Note: I followed other similar questions to change the target and minimum version. But still runs into the same error.

Thanks

Comment: I would try to run the `setup.exe` versions of these [Visual C++ runtime downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads). And maybe skim [this aging blog about the Universal CRT](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-universal-crt/). Are you using the most recent Windows 10 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, this is because your current system version is lower than the minimum version required by the application.

The safer way is to upgrade the system. The current version of your system is 17763 (1809), you need to upgrade to at least 18362 (1903).

Here is the download address of the upgrade tool: [Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

---

Another way is to reduce the minimum version requirements of the application.

Right-click the UWP application project, select `Properties` , and change the **Min version** to a lower version (such as 17763).

If the entire solution contains projects other than UWP application projects (such as some class libraries), the minimum version also needs to be adjusted.

This is not a safe method. Because some APIs used by the application may only be provided in versions 18362 and above, the version cannot be lowered in this case.